# Bad pratice in ajax request appending html in a django template

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax

In my page, I have all the objects of the DB displayed, with template tags I for loop the queryset to make every object displayed in a card.

I want to filter these objects by category (which is a parameter) without refreshing the page so I made an ajax request which gets a JSON with the filtered objects and displays them.

The ajax function works fine but involves some bad practice as you can see in the code below.

```py
# my view
class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Item
    paginate_by = 4
    template_name = "home-page.html"
```

```html
//relevant part of my template
<div class="row wow fadeIn" id="hardwarelist">
{% for item in object_list %}
          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="view overlay">
                  <img src="{{item.image}}" class="card-img-top" alt="" 
                   height="330" width="330">
                <a href="{{ item.get_absolute_url }}">
                  <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body text-center">
                <a href="" class="grey-text">
                  <h5>{{ item.get_category_display }}</h5>
                </a>
                <h5>
                  <strong>
                    <a href="{{ item.get_absolute_url }}" class="dark-grey- 
                     text">{{item.title}}<br/>
                      <span class="badge badge-pill
                      {{ item.get_label_display }}-color">
                      {{item.label}} 
                      </span>
                    </a>
                  </strong>
                </h5>
```

```js
// ajax function
// bad pratice here, I append the card html tag by tag changing template tags
// like {{item.title}} with js variables like objects.title,
// basically I append all the html diplayed above and it's clearly bad pratice
function ajax() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/ecommerce/list-api/' + urlJson + '?format=json',
        success: function(objects) {
            $.each(objects, function(i, object){
                            $hardwarelist.append(<div> + object.title + 
                                                 </div>)
// here I go on appending every html line
            });
        },
        error: function() {
                alert('errore caricamento Oggetti');
                }
        });

}
})
```

How can I do this without using .append?

I tried moving the Html of my card in another file and include that in the "home-page.html" but I can't handle objects.

If it's not clear I can post relevant sections of my code,
any suggestions or hints are really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: are you getting json in ajax response?

Comment: Make sure you are getting json in the success callback the objects paramter. Then you can iterate your objects array and format your html strings once done append to the div

Comment: yes the ajax request is working good, I get a json with filtered objects, the problem is how to display these objects in the template, I don't think appending html is the best way to do so.

Comment: I dont see it bad if you dont like it select element and do `$("#element_id").html()`

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari are you suggesting to use .format instead of .append? I could try

Comment: Amm you can let the loop complete build the html and call `.html()` onwhole element it self